# smooth ( complex valued) functions "divisible" by $\mathbb{z}^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, complex-numbers

Let $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ be an open set containing $0$. Is it possible to construct a smooth function $f : U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ satisfying:

1. $f(0 ) = 0$
2. The function $g:U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, defined by $g(z) = z^2 f(z)$, is a diffeomorphism onto its image.

(Hope: no).

Comment: Smooth = holomorphic?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla No. Smooth means smooth.

Comment: I mean a smooth function in the sense of differential geometry. If $f$ happens to be holomorphic then the answer to the question is no.

Comment: @NickL You can compute $\frac{g(z)-g(0)}{z}=zf(z)$, which tends to $0$ when $z\to0$. Therefore, the function has complex derivative, and the value of that is $0$ at $z=0$. In particular the differential at that point is $0$.

Comment: Thanks SphericalTriangle!

Comment: So this implies the Jacobian vanishes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any function $h$ satisfying $|h(z)|\le C|z|^2$ in a neighborhood of $0$ satisfies $Dh(0)=0$ in the real sense. This falls right out of the definition of "differentiable". And yes, $Dh(0)=0$ iff $J_h(0)$ is the zero matrix.